# How do you integrate $e^{x^2}$ over a closed interval?

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

I am having trouble with this integral
$$
I = \iint_D e^{x^2} dxdy\\
\text{where $D$ is the triangle with corners $(0,0)$, $(-1,0)$ och $(-1,1)$} 
$$
I have seen examples of solutions to similar integrals, but I still can't solve this one.

I see that (**edit:** marked the error in red)
$$
\iint_D e^{x^2} dxdy = \int_{-1}^0\int_0^{\color{red}{1-x}}e^{x^2}dydx
$$
$$
\begin{cases} t&=1-x\\x&=1-t\\dx&=-dt\end{cases}
$$
I try to integrate with respect to $y$ to get some expression similar to $xe^{x^2}$ (instead of $e^{x^2}$) that I can integrate:
$$
\int_0^t e^{(t-1)^2} dy = \left[ ye^{(t-x)^2} \right]_0^t = te^{(t-1)^2}
$$
Integrate with respect to $t$ by substituting $x=1-t$ and $dx = -dt$:

**edit:** I marked the mistake pointed out by [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2798002/556042) in red here (should have been $te^{t^2}e^{-2t}e$). The big mistake I made, was pointed out in the accepted answer.
$$
\begin{align}
I &= \int_{-1}^0 te^{(t-1)^2} dx = \int_2^1 \color{red}{te^{(t-1)^2}}\cdot (-1)~dt
\\&=-\int_2^1 \left(\color{red}{te^{t^2} + te^{-2t} + te} \right)dt = -\left[ \int\left(te^{t^2} + te^{-2t} + te \right)dt \right]_2^1
\end{align}
$$
But this integral is evaluated ([wolfram alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=-%5Cint_2%5E1%20(te%5E%7Bt%5E2%7D%20%2B%20te%5E%7B-2t%7D%20%2B%20te%20)dt)) to
$$
e + e^4/2 - \frac{5e^{-4}}{4} + \frac{3e^{-2}}{4}
$$
while the correct answer is supposed to be
$$
\frac{e-1}{2}
$$
so obviously I'm doing something wrong early. How do you solve this kind of integral?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The region you are integrating over is bounded by the lines $y=0$, $x=-1$ and $y=-x$. So if you set up the right integral, we see that

$$\iint_De^{x^2} dydx=\int_{-1}^0\int_{0}^{-x} e^{x^2} dydx=\int_{-1}^0-xe^{x^2}dx$$
Now substitute $u=x^2$, then $du=2xdx$ and the lower bound becomes $(-1)^2$ so $$\iint_D e^{x^2}dx=-\frac{1}{2}\int_{1}^0e^udu=-\frac{1}{2}\bigg(1-e\bigg)=\frac{e-1}{2}$$

Comment: Forgot some differentials

Comment: (+1) your answer showed up while I was writing mine.

Comment: @Adam a problem with quickness.

Comment: @Adam you're totally right, I think it was my enthousiastic typing which accidentally made me skip them. Thanks for your edit.

Comment: This is the reason why I've been stuck on the problem for so long. **note to self:** make sketches clearer.

Answer (score 3):

Your mistake is here: $$e^{(t-1)^2} = e^{t^2}e^{-2t}e$$, 
not a sum of those exponentials.

Comment: Thanks! I will edit this in the post since the main reason was the thing mentioned in the accepted answer.